# View visible in View Hirearchy debugger but not on Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit

I want to add and remove views at runtime in a stack view but am not able to do it.
Basically the situation is I am using a `Button` made from a `Xib` and adding it to a `StackView`, Stack View Distribution is `fill equally` and alignment is `fill` but the problem is that the button is not resizing according to the stack view.

I mean if I give initialiser a frame rect `.zero` then it's invisible, If I give it a `CGRect(0,0,40,40)` then it's a 40x40 square but don't resizes properly.

The main confusion and problem is it looks as expected in View Hierarchy Debugger but results on simulator don't translates in the same way attached some screenshots for reference and I also added some blank `UIView` and they are working as expected.

**Code for rendering in ViewController**

```
 func render(viewModel: ViewModel) {
    let rentalButton = MyCustomButton(frame: .zero)
    let shiftingButton = MyCustomButton(frame: .zero)
    rentalButton.titleText = "Rental button"
    shiftingButton.titleText = "Shifting button"
    rentalButton.subtitleText = "subtitle rental"
    shiftingButton.subtitleText = "subtitle shifting"
    

    for view in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
      stackView.removeArrangedSubview(view)
      view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    
    let black = UIView()
    black.backgroundColor = .black
    let red = UIView()
    red.backgroundColor = .red
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(shiftingButton)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(black)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(rentalButton)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(red)
    
    if viewModel.showRental && !viewModel.showHouseShifting {
      rentalButton.showSubtitle = true
      shiftingButton.showSubtitle = false
      stackView.removeArrangedSubview(shiftingButton)
      shiftingButton.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    else if !viewModel.showRental &&  viewModel.showHouseShifting {
      rentalButton.showSubtitle = false
      shiftingButton.showSubtitle = true
      stackView.removeArrangedSubview(rentalButton)
      rentalButton.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    
    stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    rentalButton.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
```

**Init Code for my Button from Xib**

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self._init()
  }
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    self._init()
  }
  
  private func _init() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyCustomButton", owner: self, options: nil)
    
    self.addSubview(self.contentView)
    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds
    self.contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    
    setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
    self.matchConstraints(toView: contentView)
    decorate()
  }
```

[image: Simulator output]

[image: View hierarchy debugger output]

[image: View hierarchy debugger output]